# "Swap" a stacked bar in python (Pandas + matplotlib)

Tags: python, pandas, plot, data-visualization

I was doing some data visualization and discovered a small problem (for me) to show the data.
I'm using the [Haberman Survival Data Set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Haberman's+Survival) and there's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



data = pd.read_table('haberman.data', sep = ",")
data['lived'] = data['lived'].map({ 1: 'Yes', 2: 'No'})

dataYear = data.sort_values(['year'])

plot1 = dataYear.groupby('year')['lived'].value_counts()
#plot1.unstack().head()


my_plot = plot1.unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked = True, title="Patients X Year")
my_plot.set_xlabel("Year")
my_plot.set_ylabel("Total")
plt.show()
```

So my intention is to see if the Year of Treatment can contribute to patient cure. This code generates this beautiful graph:

[My graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQIeq.png)

I just want to swap the No (Blue) from bottom to above the Yes (Green).
Probabbly the pandas have a "secret" parameter (yeah, I searched in the doc of pandas.plot and matplotlib) or maybe it is something more complex and involves arranging the data.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



data = pd.read_table('haberman.data', sep = ",")
data['lived'] = data['lived'].map({ 1: 'Yes', 2: 'No'})

dataYear = data.sort_values(['year'])

plot1 = dataYear.groupby('year')['lived'].value_counts()
#plot1.unstack().head()


my_plot = plot1.unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked = True, title="Patients X Year")
my_plot.set_xlabel("Year")
my_plot.set_ylabel("Total")
plt.show()
handles, labels = my_plot.get_legend_handles_labels()
my_plot.legend(reversed(handles), reversed(labels)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, but it does not work. (I also tried moving the new lines in code, But the chart did not change).